# AWS NLB in public subnets with EC2 in private subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, vpc

Has someone configured a NLB in the public subnets of your VPC to route traffic to EC2 instances that are in the private subnets?

When using an ELB, a good solution is to create a Security Group for the ELB and then create another SecurityGroup for the private EC2 Instances, allowing incoming traffic from that ELB Security Group, as explained here:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/public-load-balancer-private-ec2/

"You can also add a rule on the instance’s security group to allow traffic from the security group assigned to the load balancer. For example, if the security group on the load balancer is sg-1234567a, make the following changes on the security group associated with the private instances"

Since you cannot associate a Security Group to a NLB, how could you accomplish this with the same type of security?

Thanks!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Since you cannot associate a Security Group to a NLB, how could you
>   accomplish this with the same type of security?

The security aspect does not change.

NLB is a different beast, it not the same as classic Load Balancers. For Classic Load Balancers, from the point of view of your instances, traffic does appear to come from inside the VPC. From outside, traffic goes to a (random and mutating) list of IP addresses, resolved by the DNS record that AWS provides to you.

Network Load Balancers are completely different. From the point of view of your instances, they are completely invisible. If it is an external network load balancer, traffic appears to be coming from instances on the internet directly (even though this is an illusion). Therefore, if you want to talk to everyone on the internet, 0.0.0.0/0 is what you open it to.

This is, in fact, what the documentation says:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-register-targets.html#target-security-groups

```
Recommended Rules

Inbound Source      Port Range        Comment
Client IP addresses instance listener Allow traffic from clients on the instance listener port

VPC CIDR            health check      Allow traffic from the load balancer on the health check port
```

Client IP addresses is whatever your client IPs are. If they are on the open internet, 0.0.0.0/0 it is. Adding the NLB private IP address, as I saw in other responses, accomplishes nothing. Traffic is not coming from there, as far as the instances are concerned.

On the security angle, nothing changes. Since your instances are in private subnets, traffic cannot flow directly to them, as there is a NAT gateway in the middle. It can only flow from them to the internet (through NAT gateway, then internet gateway). Even if you specify all traffic is allowed from everywhere, traffic still won't come. It will have to come through another way. In your case, that way is the NLB, which has a fixed number of ports it listens to, and only sends traffic to the destination ports on the instances you specify.

If you are moving from classic Load Balancers to NLBs, move the security group rules from the Load Balancer to your instances. Or better yet, since you can have multiple security groups, just add the SG you currently have for the classic LB to the instances(and update any ASGs as needed). Your security posture will be exactly the same. With the added benefit that now your applications won't need things like proxy protocol to figure out where traffic is coming from, it is no longer obfuscated by the load balancer.

Answer (score 15):

That is indeed true as per AWS Documentation :

> Network Load Balancers do not have associated security groups.
>   Therefore, the security groups for your targets must use IP addresses
>   to allow traffic from the load balancer.

So If you do not want to grant access to the entire VPC CIDR, you can grant access to the private IP addresses used by the load balancer nodes. There is one IP address per load balancer subnet.

On NLB Tab of there is one Network Interface per Load Balancer from there :

> On the Details tab for each network interface, copy the address from
>   Primary private IPv4 IP.

You can use this private IP Address at add it SG of EC2 Instances.

Please Refer to [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/target-group-register-targets.html#target-security-groups)

Comment: Thanks Kush. I tried that and it works for the NLB Health Checks. For the HTTP traffic coming from the clients, it does not work. You still have to open the HTTP traffic from everywhere in the Security Group of the private EC2 instances. Doesn´t that go against the idea of having those private EC2 Instances just accepting traffic from your ELB/NLB/ALB?

Comment: yes that is why you add the private IP of the nlb to allowed in sg of ec2

Comment: but even if you add the private IP of the NLB (for the health checks), you also have to open HTTP traffic from source 0.0.0.0/0 (everywhere)

Comment: I think the trick here, that those EC2 instances should only have a private IP, so adding the source 0.0.0.0/0 wouldn't mean much without the NLB sending the traffic (from its private IP), but the source IP is shown as public.

Comment: This is wrong, IPs assigned to NLB rotate periodically.....

Answer (score 0):

Tail your http access logs and you will see there is no changing of source IP address from the network load balancer which means you need to allow 0.0.0.0/0 on the endpoints security group if the internet needs access to your endpoint.
This is only ok if you use a private subnet so be careful if you have this server on a public subnet as this solution would not be advisable. In this case just use an application load balancer. You can still setup the same listener and configure a target group by instance as well. The application load balancer will update the source IP address to it's own private address if you tail the access logs. The advantage of this is you only need to allow https traffic to the app load balancer and then you can accept http for the target group if you like from the load balancer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).